# How to implement logging functionality in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension and have a need for logging -- not as in console-based logging, but in the traditional sense of a logfile (the extension monitors for certain events and logs them to the filesystem).

First, I tried the filesystem API calls.  In general this seems to be the right API, but the issue is that I need to provide the OS-level path to the generated log file to the user of my extension, and I can't see a way to do that.  I can find the physical sandboxed file (in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/003/p/00/00000000`), but I'm not sure how to get that value programatically (nor if I should).

I also tried the `FileSaver.js` implementation by Eli Grey (using Blob and `saveAs()`).  This does let me save a file to the filesystem (and specify the filename), but it requires writing the entire file every time, obviously not a good idea for a log file.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm asking?  I know there is the other answer of NPAPI, but I don't have the skills nor the build infrastructure to use it.

Thanks!