# How to write log for my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

what I need to know is how does my Chrome extension write its own log in .txt file? I tried using fileStorage but it says undefined.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134696/how-to-implement-logging-functionality-in-a-chrome-extension and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702920/looking-for-the-best-way-to-store-log-data

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Both questions are incomplete (one even has 0 answers). I would also recommend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153979/chrome-extension-how-to-save-a-file-on-disk for a way to "export" the log file.